# Executing a command shell from popen and set other command shell

Tags: c++, linux, popen, mavlink

I'm working in a project with a quadrotor and mavlink. I have successfully installed mavproxy in my Ubuntu PC and and ran it without problems from terminal. When I run `mavproxy.py` from the terminal and connected a quadrotor with support for mavlink (APM autopilot), mavproxy detects the quadrotor and everything is ok.

When you execute `mavproxy.py` the program in the terminal begin to send and receive several parameters. You can write in the terminal some parameter to access for any configuration. For example, the command `help` in the terminal:

```
$ mavlink.py
.
.data beging
.
STABILIZE>  "when the program finish the configuration, allowed to you for doing an input any parameter, for example help"

STABILIZE>help
show all helps.
```

I have a code to execute `mavlink.py` from C++

```
include <iostream>
include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
FILE *in;
char buff[512];

if(!(in = popen("mavlink.py", "r"))){
    return 1;
}

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
    cout << buff;
}
pclose(in);

return 0;
}
```

When I run this C++ program the terminal shows the same things that would appear if I were running `mavproxy.py` from the terminal, but I don´t know how can I send a command such as `help` in the C++ code.

If you read the program, the `while` statement allows me to capture the parameters generated from the program `mavproxy.py` and `cout` in the terminal, but `mavlink.py` never ends until you write something in the terminal exit or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> so the `while` loop never ends.

I have been reading about the Popen function, but I haven't found the correct form to do this.

I know that I can use the `mavlink.h` library in my program and send parameters to the quadrotor, but don't want do this with `mavlink.h`.

Comment: If you want to both read and write have a search for popen2.  It isn't part of the standard library but there are implementations out there.

Comment: i was trying to do something with pepen2 with c++; i can see it is also used in python, do you have an example in phyton? an example where you call another phyton scrip from your principal py program? thanks

Comment: @user3574324 did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue.. Please get back ASAP! Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think you want to send commands to `mavlink.py` as well as read its output.

If that is the case, you must change the open mode of `popen()` from "`r`" to "`w`" so you can write, then you can send commands to it like this:

```
FILE *fp;
char *command="HELP";

if(!(fp = popen("mavlink.py", "w"))){
    return 1;

fwrite(command, sizeof(char), strlen(command), fp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been reading about this function, popen, and all i could found is that this function is used for, read and write files, so, if i use the code you wrote, i think it will write inside the source code of mavlink.py. My purpose is, run mavlink.py from c++ code and when it is running, i want to be able to send commands , like "help". It is posible with your code? with this code i can send the command help when mavlink.py is running?. there is another option, it's change c++ to python, but i don't have experience in python